# Change bootstrap-select width

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sass, single-page-application

I am using angular 7 and created a selectDirective for handling bootstrap-select instantiation in the application.

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  // wrapping in setTimeout to delay init until after attribute binding
  jQuery(this.el).selectpicker({
    iconBase: 'fa',
    tickIcon: 'fa-check'
  });
}
```

In my html of the component (where I use the directive):

```html
<div id="filters">
  <select selectDirective
          class="status-filter show-tick"
          multiple="multiple"
          title="select filter">
    <option>abc</option>
    <option>def</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and the scss for the same is

```scss
#filters {
  .status-filter {
    width:275px !important;
  }
}
```

Now when I check the component, it is still using the default width of 220px provided in bootstrap-select then 275px provided, however the inner select gets 275px width. It seems that bootstrap-select isn't taking my nested scss in consideration while creating the structure for it's component.

How I can make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your select is nested inside many tag of you template so you need to use deep to target deep nesting element in css

```css
/deep/ #filters{
 .status-filter{
        width:275px!important;
 }
}
```

Comment: using deep worked but in the angular doc deep is considered to be deprecated. Also when I check my rendered component the div generated:   <div class="dropdown bootstrap-select show-tick status-filter"> and the inner select: <select _ngcontent-c4="" bootstrapselect="" class="status-filter show-tick" multiple="multiple" title="select filter" tabindex="-98"> and the width is applied successfully on inner select but not on outer div (the first div, dynamically generated through code mentioned in directive class). It seems directive isn't using the css.

Comment: Right now angualr team does not make announcement what we can use to replcae deep in the future so we have to wait